# Increment value in specific textview with button click in recyclerview

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, counter, increment

I am working on an app that displays images using recycler view and volley.I have imageview, textview and buttons in each card. I am trying to add functionality to my button that when clicked, will count the number of clicks and display it in a textview. When i click the button, all the textviews in all d rows are updated with the same number of clicks no matter which button was clicked on any row. I want only d row in which d button was clicked's textview to be updated.What am i doing wrong? This is the code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    int count = 0;

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {



        //Getting the particular item from the list
        SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());
        holder.textViewLikes.setText(superHero.getLikes());

        holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count ++;
                holder.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

                }

            });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public TextView textViewLikes;
        public TextView txtCount;
        public ImageButton custom_button;
        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlikes);
            txtCount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            custom_button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: You are updating a variable that is defined as a class member (`count`). Your viewholder should have its own counter for each instance, then use that value for each card.

Comment: have u got any solution am also looking and struggle like that problem,recycler view with likes count for each row item any number of times able to like and that likes count data from api how to update the api response on particular list item view